# Adding CORE PLOT HEADER to the XCODE PROJECT

Tags: ios4

I can't seem to make Xcode find the Core Plot header. I've done the following:

1. Clone the hg repo;
2. Drag the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj file into my project;
3. Opened the CP project and compiled it successfully;
4. Dragged the lib file into the target's static link list;
5. Added CorePlot-CocoaTouch as a direct dependency for the target.

But I'm still getting the "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: No such file or directory" error on compile. I've been googling around trying to find an answer, but only seem to find a few people having the same problem but no clear solution. What have I missed?

Please help me getting out of it.....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your header search paths contain a reference to the core-plot source directory.

In your targets Build Settings set `Header Search Paths` to the core-plot/framework directory. For example when your core-plot directory is placed next to your project directoy the search path would contain a value of `../core-plot/framework/**`  (I'm using a recursive reference here, thus the ** at the end).

Comment: Do you have to add this for Ad Hoc, Debug, and Release separately?  Where do you type that?

Answer (score 0):

Do not miss :-

1-Do not forget to add the library to Target dependance **under the "Targets" source list that appears. Click on the "Build Phases" tab and expand the "Target Dependencies" group. Click on the plus button, select the CorePlot-CocoaTouch library, and click Add. This should ensure that the Core Plot library will be built with your application.**
[image]

2- Core Plot is built as a static library for iPhone, so you'll need to drag the libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a static library from under the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj group to the "Link Binaries With Libraries" group within the application target's "Build Phases" group you were just in. 
[image]

3 Under your Build settings, set the Header Search Paths to the relative path from your application to the framework/ subdirectory within the Core Plot source tree. Make sure to make this header search path recursive. You need to add -ObjC to Other Linker Flags as well (as of Xcode 4.2, -all_load does not seem to be needed, but it may be required for older Xcode versions). -Header Search Paths : you must put the relative path for libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a and it is too much important to check the recursive check-box.

Finally the following link may can help you...
http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this blog](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application) might help more than the google source page of CorePlot.

For newbies it might be helpful to use the mac shell to get the relative path of the libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a. Just open the Terminal and insert following line:

```
mdfind -name libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a
```

you will get listed all paths that contain the file named "libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a"